# What's SQL table name for table between 'Users' and 'UserTypes'?

Tags: sql-server, naming-conventions

i have two tables in my database :

- Users : contain user information
- UserTypes : contain the names of user types ( student , teacher , specialist ) - I can't rename it to 'Types' as we have a table with this name

relation between Users and UserTypes many to many .. so i'll create a table that have UserID(FK) with UserTypeID(FK) but I try to find best name for that table ... any suggestion please ?

Comment: I see @DVK and @rmalayter answers are good but i prefer @Waleed style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend following whatever naming conventions that your coding guidelines - you do have on right? - state for these types of tables. If you don't have a guideline, then  something like this might work:

Users_UserTypes

Answer (score 1):

I think a good practice would be to call it something like "Users_UserTypes", possibly prefixed with some conventional codeword you invent for this purpose.  That's what happens in my application, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have anything other the "type" in the UserTypes table? How many entries are there? If there's only a few, and it doesn't contain any additional data, then I would simply denormalise that table and don't have a separate joiner at all.

That is:

```
Users:

  ID       |  First Name      |  Last Name
-----------+------------------+--------------------
 123       | John             | Smith
 456       | Jane             | Doe

UserTypes:

  UserID   |  Type
-----------+----------------
 123       | student
 123       | specialist
 456       | teacher
```

The "Type" column doesn't have to be a string, it could be an integer that's mapped to an enumeration in your code or whatever you like.

IMO, there's not much point denormalising things to the point where you've got 500 tables all joining together all the time...

Comment: we think in these idea but the problem that many developers work in this Database during different period and if it's a just numbers without meaning developers will not be able to understand it meaning specially some can't able to see some code that explained that so we prefer to make it as an existing table in db

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (besides Users_UserTypes) would be `UserTypes_for_Users` It's a bit less conventional but IMHO more understandable

Answer (score 1):

User, UserType (I name every table singular) and... UserTypeMap

Answer (score 0):

We use an Table1_x_Table2 naming convention for many-to-many tables.

This makes things quite clear, and indicates the cross-reference nature of the table:
Person_x_Company
Package_x_Product
User_x_UserType

For self-relation tables, such as employee-to-manager, we have a Person_x_Person table with a "relation_type" and "priority" column, to allow multiple managers per employee with a primary versus secondary manager.